# Firefox Ghost Image Shrinks When Dragging Large Elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

Is there any way to prevent Firefox from rendering a ghost image that is way smaller than the source element when dragging large elements?

I've created a [sample page](http://www.lonniebest.com/GhostImageBug/) and [video](https://youtu.be/hrxUO4aqHD4), if you do not understand what I'm talking about.

This downsized ghost-image is problematic in applications where the user is dragging a large element to an absolute position; when the user tries to drop the dragged element to an exact location, it doesn't drop where they're trying to drop it. Only after several blind attempts, can they place the dragged element exactly where they want it.

In Chromium 69, the element drops exactly where the user tries to drop it, because the ghost image is exactly the same size as the source element.

If you can think of additional reasons against this default behavior in Firefox, please voice them at the bug I've submitted [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1495361).

In the meantime, I'm looking for a work-around.

The ghost image is ideal, because it looks exactly like what's being dragged. I know its possible to have custom drag-images, but I can't think of a way to make that custom image look exactly like the element being dragged (like the ghost image achieves).

I may have to settle for just making a generic image that can at least be sized correctly during drag and drop. Any other ideas?